# Why does inverse fourier transformation have a $\frac{1}{N}$ term?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've been trying to learn the Discrete Fourier Transformation (DFT) and the Inverse DFT (IDFT).

From Wikipedia, I gather we can define the matrix transformations for the DFT as follows. Let $\omega= e^{-2\pi i/N}$ and let $$\mathbf{W}= \left[\frac{\omega^{jk}}{\sqrt{N}}\right]_{j,k=0,\cdots,N-1}$$

Then we can take a vector $\mathbf{x}$ and transform it via

$$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}$$

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix

**Question 1:** Does the DFT always involve a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ term? I noticed that in many cases it seems defined without that, e.g.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Now, $\mathbf{W}$ is a unitary matrix and therefore $\mathbf{W}^{*}\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{I}_{N}$. I have read that the IDFT is then defined as

$$\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{W}^{*}\mathbf{X}$$

Source: https://www.kth.se/social/upload/50919490f2765474b1890dde/lec2.pdf

Ok, so if we put these together

$$\mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{W}^{*}\mathbf{X} =  \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{W}^{*}\left(\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}\right)=\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{I}_{N}\mathbf{x}=\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{x}$$

which obviously doesn't make any sense.

**Question 2:**
What is wrong with my definitions of the DFT and IDFT such that it isn't inverting properly?

Comment: Did you read the entire wiki entry? As with the continuous FT, there are different conventions for normalizing. If you make $\mathbf W$ unitary, there is no $1/N$. If there’s no $\sqrt N$ in the original, then you use the $1/N$.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, that's helpful. Thanks Ted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\left[\omega^{jk}\right]\left[\omega^{jk}\right]^\dagger = NI_N
$$
your forward and inverse matrices need to be multiplied by a net factor of $1/N$ for normalization. This can be accomplished by giving each a $1/\sqrt{N}$ factor, as in your first link, or by putting the full $1/N$ on the inverse matrix, as in your second two links. The matrix will only be unitary using the first convention.

You could also, hypothetically, split it up in other ways as long as the product is $1/N$, but the above two are most common.

Different normalization conventions are used by different sources, so always check which one they're using.

Comment: super helpful! this was great. thank you!